# Accessing S3 Bucket Content Locally and on Cloud without MFA Code

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, aws-sdk, aws-cli, multi-factor-authentication

I have set up an S3 bucket in my AWS account with 2FA enabled. I need to read the bucket's contents both locally and on the cloud. I found documentation mentioning options for local access that require entering an MFA code from the authenticator app.
However, I'm seeking alternative methods for running a script on the cloud that don't involve entering an MFA code. Can someone provide guidance on this?

I have tried `aws sts get-session-token --serial-number <mfaSerialCode> --token-code <mfaCode>` which works in AWS CLI and the same also works in script.

Looking for ways which do not require entering mfaCode.